# Не срабатывает фунция execve() в Linux

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, g++

При компиляции через g++ 5.4.0 этого кода получаю вывод, из которого могу судить, что execve попросту не срабатывает. Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему?
Исходный код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <cstring>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (argc > 1)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
        {
            std::cout << argv[i] << std::endl;
        }

        return 0;
    }

    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Error creating process" << std::endl;
    }
    else if (pid == 0)
    {
        //child
        std::cout << "Hello from Child" << std::endl;

        char** params = new char*[5];

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            params[0] = new char[10];
        }

        strcpy(params[0], "1st");
        strcpy(params[1], "2nd");
        strcpy(params[2], "3rd");
        params[3] = nullptr;

        execve("test", params, nullptr);
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        //parent
        waitpid(pid, nullptr, 0);

        std::cout << "Hello from parent" << std::endl;
    }

    std::cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Сам вывод:

```
Hello from Child
Hello from parent
```

P.S. Компилировал с параметром `-std=c++11`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исправьте-ка код

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    params[0] = new char[10];
}
```

Зачем присваивать указатель одной и той же переменной `params[0]` целых три раза?...

Comment: Спасибо, так сработало. Но мне требуется эти строки генерировать в динамической памяти. В общем случае требуется неопределенное количество параметров неопределенной длины

Comment: Тогда корректно присваивайте указатели...

Comment: благодарю, не заметил опечатку

Comment: Ну, тогда пометьте ответ как принятый :)

Comment: Строго говоря, вопросам о проблемах, заключающихся в простой опечатке, не место на SO

Comment: Вы не поверите, этот пример собирался число для задания вопроса, т.к. основной проект, где он возникал, я пытался починить в течении 3,5 часов. И там не срабатывал этот же блок. К сожалению (а может и к счастью), там была проблема с makefile, а точнее с тем, как он запускал закомпиленные исходники.